# Install python package for python2.7 with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install pre-commit for python2.7 with pip 8.1.2.

If i do `pip install --user pre-commit` or ´python -m pip install --user pre-commit´ it keeps trying to load pre-commit3.0.2 and failing.

So i tried to find the most recent version that still supports python2.7 (by manually going through the version history, is there not better way?) and that is 1.21.0.

But even when i do pip install --user pre-commit==1.21.0 it fails due to

```
Collecting virtualenv>=15.2 (from pre-commit==1.21.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/19/65f13cff26c8cc11fdfcb0499cd8f13388dd7b35a79a376755f152b42d86/virtualenv-20.17.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mjJnKQ/virtualenv/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("setuptools >= 41 required to build")
    RuntimeError: setuptools >= 41 required to build
```

which i assume is because virtualenv-20.17.1 requires python3

Comment: First upgrade: `pip2.7 install --upgrade "pip<21.0" "setuptools<45"`

Comment: Well, the error message says `setuptools >= 41 required to build`. What version of `setuptools` is present. Did you try upgrading that?

Comment: Also, just want to make sure: you understand that Python 2.7 has been past EOL for three years now?

Comment: @phd 
that gives me this `Successfully installed pip-8.1.2 setuptools-20.1.1` after which the installation still fails

@KarlKnechtel well aware. for all of my own stuff i am using 3.10.
But thats what my working group at university is still using... and upgrading would also mean upgrading other stuff and there are not tests so noone has the time to move it and make sure everything still works ;(

Comment: Do it step by step: `pip2.7 install --upgrade "pip==9.0.1"` and then `pip2.7 install --upgrade "pip<21.0" "setuptools<45"`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think pre-commit is not supported for Python 2.7 and starts only in 3.7 but you can write a custom hook or any other tools that you are using for linting based on the IDE you are using.The hook would need to check for any errors in the code before committing, and if any errors are found, it should fail the commit and display a warning message.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pre-commit/1.21.0/ says that there should be a version that works with python2.7